# error 404 page is not displayed

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a little problem with my ERROR 404 page. In my .htaccess file I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301, NE]
```

the code for add "/" to the end of URL. This code works fine on all pages, but when I use it for error 404 page, web browser don' t show my own error 404 page, but show ERROR 403 page of my webhosting provider. So, when I use "http://www.recension4u.com/error" it works fine, but when I use "http://www.recension4u.com/error/" it makes the problem. Please can you help me? For all advice thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code. It may help you.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I try it, but the problem is still the same. And I have one question: this 4 lines must be in .htaccess with my 2 lines or without? Because when I try add this 4 lines and not delete my 2 lines it cause ERROR 500, but when I delete my 2 lines, it still doesn't work right.